# when close the top window ,how to let the focus to the next level window?

Tags: cocoa

Now I clicked a button in the mainwindow and show a modal window ,then in the modal I clicked a button to show another modal window , now I found When I closed the top modal window ,the focus didn't in the next level modal window , I open the modal window used the func:
[NSApp runModalForWindow: ]; How to let the focus in the next level modal window when closed the top level modal window?

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, you shouldn't really be running modal sessions inside modal sessions. Not only is it *really* bad UI, it's quite complex to get right.

Have a look at Apple's modal session documentation for detailed information on modal sessions: http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Concepts/UsingModalWindows.html